# How to get file's owner from NSCoder

Tags: objective-c, nscoder

I'm trying to embed a custom `UIView` subclass using interface builder into a nib, but the custom view's nib is in another nib. So I use `awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` to dynamically select the correct nib for the custom `UIView`. Only issue is the file's owner does not get passed to the new nib.

I need to get the file's owner for the nib from the `NSCoder` passed into `awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` so I can properly set it on the replacement object when using `[nib instantiateWithOwner:owner options:nil];`.

Anyone know how to get the file's owner from an `NSCoder` object?